# AWS S3 Block Size to calculate total number of mappers for Hive Workload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

Does S3 stores the data in form of blocks? if yes, what is the default block size? Is there a way to alter the block size?

Answer (score 0):

Block Size is not applicable to Amazon S3. It is an object storage system, not a virtual disk.

Comment: In that case, how total number of mappers will be calculated by EMR cluster?

Comment: I'm not sure. Just let Amazon EMR figure things out. You _might_ want to change it if there is a performance problem, but see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

There is believed to be some partitioning of uploaded data into the specific blocks it was uploaded -and if you knew those values then readers *may* get more bandwidth. But certainly the open source hive/spark/mapreduce applications don't know the API calls to find this information out or look at these details. Instead the S3 connector takes some configuration option (for s3a: `fs.s3a.block.size`) to simulate blocks.

It's not so beneficial to work out that block size if it took an HTTP GET request against each file to determine the partitioning...that would slow down the (Sequential) query planning before tasks on split files were farmed out to the worker nodes. HDFS lets you get the listing and block partitioning + location in one API call (`listLocatedStatus(path)`); S3 only has a list call to return the list of (objects, timestamps, etags) under a prefix, (S3 List API v2) so that extra check would slow things down. If someone could fetch that data and show that there'd be benefits, maybe it'd be useful enough to implement. For now, calls to `S3AFIleSystem.listLocatedStatus()` against S3 just get some made up list of locations splitting of blocks by the `fs.s3a.block.size` value and with the location (localhost). All the apps known that location == localhost means "whatever"